# Express.js routing with default route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following Express.js code:

```
router = express.Router()
fs.readdirSync('./controllers').forEach(function (file) {
  if(file.substr(-3) == '.js') {
      route = require('./controllers/' + file);
      route.controller(router);
  }
});
app.use('/', router);
```

It works good. I don't set path for '/' route in my controllers, and my Express.js server renders 'index.html' from 'public' folder by default - this is what I want. Now I want to add '*' route, so Express.js return 'index.html' from 'public' folder - it's static file, no need to render, just returning. How can i do it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your service to serve up `public/index.html` from your root path you can simply use `express.static` like this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

express.static will treat `index.html` as your index file by default, and you can configure this in the 2nd argument:

```
app.use(express.static('public', {index: 'myIndex.html'}))
```

Note also that you don't have to specify the root to `app.use` the way you are. Simply do this:

```
app.use(router);
```

I would even suggest that your `route.controller()` methods are not necessary. If each of your controllers exported their own `express.Router()` you could simply do `app.use(myController)` in your iterator.